# SPF record e-mail appearing as SOFTFAIL instead of FAIL?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

I added a SPF record a few days ago to our company DNS

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.messagelabs.com -all"
```

and now I am sending a fake e-mail with my company e-mail address as the from address using the website at https://emkei.cz

Then I check my personal e-mail (iCloud) and see the fake e-mail supposedly from my company e-mail in my Inbox and when I check the headers it says

```
Received SPF: softfail
```

but that website uses mail server `emkei.cz [46.167.245.118]` which is not defined in our SPF record, so the fail should be a HARDFAIL because we use `-all` (and message put in Junk or something), right?

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using include, your SPF will be redirected to the SPF of "included" domain. SPF for spf.messagelabs.com is

```
"v=spf1 include:nets1.spf.messagelabs.com include:nets2.spf.messagelabs.com ~all"
```

~all is the reason, why you have softfail instead of hardfail.

Comment: Replace your SPF with "v=spf1 include:nets1.spf.messagelabs.com include:nets2.spf.messagelabs.com -all" and then try. It should work correctly.

Comment: As I understand it, the include mechanism should not match when the included domain return softfail (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-5.2). The resolver should then use the -all in the original record.